# Javascript - How using a variable for object property

Tags: javascript, object, variables, properties

Im very beginner in javascript, i would like to use all variable created on each object property :

```
let title = "Les Miserables";
let resume = "Blabla blaaabla...";
let autor = "Victor Hugo"
let date = "1862"

const books = {
        title: title,
        resume: desc,
        autor: autor,
        date: date,
      }
```

I want a result like this =>

```
{ title:'Les Miserables', resume:'Blabla blaaabla...', autor:'Victor Hugo', date: '1862'}
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Your example is working (except for mismatched `resume: desc`). What problem are you having? If your variables are all named the same as the properties you want in the object you can use [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) `const books = { title, resume, autor, date, };`

Comment: @pilchard thanks that the doc i wanted, i want use object because after that is more easy to handle each object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [object property shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#:%7E:text=Shorthand):

```js
let title = "Les Miserables";
let resume = "Blabla blaaabla...";
let autor = "Victor Hugo";
let date = "1862";

const books = {
  title,
  resume,
  autor,
  date,
};

console.log(books); /* Logs:
{
  title: "Les Miserables",
  resume: "Blabla blaaabla...",
  autor: "Victor Hugo",
  date: "1862"
} */
```

You can also assign the values directly to properties on the object instead of first declaring individual variables in the scope:

```js
const books = {};

books.title = "Les Miserables";
books.resume = "Blabla blaaabla...";
books.autor = "Victor Hugo";
books.date = "1862";

console.log(books); /* Logs:
{
  title: "Les Miserables",
  resume: "Blabla blaaabla...",
  autor: "Victor Hugo",
  date: "1862"
} */
```

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74675724/javascript-how-using-a-variable-for-object-property/74675774?noredirect=1#comment131804404_74675774) @pilchard I can see that interpretation. I added an additional example showing a simpler approach to object property assignment.